# Help with syncing the angle of a fan to the rotation of an external shaft

Tags: motors, stepper-motor

I have a 20-pound fan whose axis can rotate 360 degrees in the east-to-west plane but needs to rotate in sync with a separate external shaft. As depicted in the attached image. I plan to use an on-axis sensor to determine the angle position of the external shaft and then feed this data into a microcontroller to control the angle of the fan sweeping in the east-to-west plane using a motor. Most importantly, the fan angle needs to change in real-time with the angle of the external shaft, which at most will be rotating 20 rpms.

I was thinking of using a stepper motor to rotate the fan but I don't know which placement of the stepper motor would be better. In the image, OPTION MOTOR A is connected directly axis of the fan's housing to rotate the fan, but I'm uncertain if a motor can provide enough torque there to rotate the fan in real time with the external shaft. As opposed to OPTION MOTOR B turning a gear near the outer edge of the fan's housing.

Any advice would be appreciated as to how best to keep the rotation of the fan in sync with the rotation of the external shaft, especially in light of the external shaft operating in a range of 0 - 20 rpm.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered how those swinging fans work? Do they use 2 or 3 motors?

Comment: 20 RPM sounds very low for a fan. It's not going to push air. What are you building?

Comment: The fan spins using a motor at each end of the orange shafts of the fan housing. Also, the fan spins at 5000 rpm however it is the direction of the fan that changes by syncing it with the rotation angle of the external shaft.

Comment: Stepper motors that have no issues turning, have no issues turning 360 deg.  There are many sizes of stepper motors so get one that can do the job.  If you have the fan unit, measure what it takes to turn it and pick a motor and mounting that will work.

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I have no idea what you are describing.

Comment: I edited the post for better clarity.

Comment: I think he means he needs a pan/tilt like mechanism but pan only.  That the thing he intends to pan around the room is a fan is just confusing the matter, and mostly irrelevant to the actual needs.